# Replication Setup: 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication'

Tags: sql-server, replication

1. We are currently working on setting up replication for our web server, where the publisher/distributor server is a web server and the Subscriber is a local server - express edition. During the process of enabling the publisher, we encountered the following error:
   "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication."

[image]

We attempted to connect to the snapshot and log reader agents using both Windows authentication and SQL authentication, but unfortunately, neither approach yielded the desired results.

There are no errors when both the publisher/distributor server and the Subscriber are local servers, everything works fine.

2. If I connect to my web server by specifying the port number, then while enabling the publisher I get “must be enabled as a Publisher before you can create a publication. In the following dialog box, enable this server as a Publisher”, so if I connect to by specifying port number I get “SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, ‘MyServer‘. (Replication.Utilities)”

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve these issues for my webserver?